# How to rename all files in folders with pattern

Tags: command-line, bash, regex, rename

I have a bunch of files like:

```
bla.super.lol.S01E03.omg.bbq.mp4
bla.super.lol.S01E04.omg.bbq.mp4
bla.super.lol.s03e12.omg.bbq.mp4
```

I need to rename them all like:

```
s01e03.mp4
s01e04.mp4
s03e12.mp4
```

I've tried to do it with `for file in *; do mv $file ${file%%\.omg*}; done` but it removes only part after S01E01, not before it
so please, help

Comment: Is the number of sections always the same, or should  we work with S0 something? And what is the distibguising marker: barbeque? mp4? (probably omg looking at your attempt).

Answer (score 9):

With `rename` (`prename`):

```
rename -n 's/^bla\.super\.lol\.[sS](\d+)[eE](\d+)\..*(\.mp4$)/s$1e$2$3/' *.mp4
```

`-n` does the dry-running, if you are satisfied with the potential renaming, just remove `-n` to let the actual renamimg to take place:

```
rename 's/^bla\.super\.lol\.[sS](\d+)[eE](\d+)\..*(\.mp4$)/s$1e$2$3/' *.mp4
```

**Example:**

```
$ ls -1
bla.super.lol.S01E03.omg.bbq.mp4
bla.super.lol.S01E04.omg.bbq.mp4
bla.super.lol.s03e12.omg.bbq.mp4

$ rename -n 's/^bla\.super\.lol\.[sS](\d+)[eE](\d+)\..*(\.mp4$)/s$1e$2$3/' *.mp4
bla.super.lol.S01E03.omg.bbq.mp4 renamed as s01e03.mp4
bla.super.lol.S01E04.omg.bbq.mp4 renamed as s01e04.mp4
bla.super.lol.s03e12.omg.bbq.mp4 renamed as s03e12.mp4
```

Comment: You could also, if you know that `s\d{2}e\d{2}` will only show up once replace the `bla\.super....` with just `[A-Za-z0-9.]+` or even `.+`, since `+` is non-greedy. This would allow your answer to work for any input of the same pattern (garbage + s01e01 + garbage.mp4)

Comment: @Musher FIle renaming should not be based on any assumption..also your regex could be simplified to just `[\w.]` ..also `+` is Greedy..

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS="\n"                               # Handle files with spaces in the names
for file in *.mp4; do
    newfile="${file/bla.super.lol./}"  # Strip the prefix you don't want
    newfile="${newfile/S/s}"           # Change the first S to an s
    newfile="${newfile/E/e}"           # Change the first E to an e
    newfile="${newfile.%omg.bbq*}"     # Strip the suffix you don't want
    newfile="${newfile}.mp4}"          # Tack on the file extension again
done
if [[ "$file" == "$newfile" ]]; then
    echo "Not renaming $file - no change decreed."
elif [[ -f "$newfile" ]]; then
    echo "Not renaming $file - $newfile already exists."
else
    mv -- "$file" "$newfile"           # Make the change
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple..

```
rename 's/.*\.(\w+)\.omg\..*mp4$/\L$1.mp4/' *.mp4
```

*Example:*

```
$ echo 'bla.super.lol.S01E03.omg.bbq.mp4' | perl -pe 's/.*\.(\w+)\.omg\..*mp4$/\L$1.mp4/'
s01e03.mp4
```